# All .htaccess files in my cPanel are denying access to my website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

So recently I found out that all of the .htaccess files in my WordPress website are set to the following:

`<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$"> Order Allow,Deny Deny from all </FilesMatch>`

We're talking about over 2000 files... is there any way to change that in cPanel or WordPress?

Comment: There have been several recent questions identifying similar hacks to WordPress sites (has  a vulnerability recently been exploited?!)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165874/how-to-remove-malware-code-from-in-index-php-and-htaccess-file-in-wordpress-webs | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70111542/htaccess-files-are-repeatedly-being-created-in-file-directory | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116425/my-websites-bandwidth-skyrockets-and-this-htaccess-gets-generated-for-no-reason [DELETED]

Comment: "all of the .htaccess files in my WordPress website .... We're talking about over 2000 files" - Are you suggesting you have over 2000 `.htaccess` files?!

Comment: It sounds like they have 2000 files (like .php files) that are effected by this rule. @MrWhite

Comment: Yup, 2000 htaccess files. I went to the directory of my Wordpress website in cPanel, deleted those 2000 files. Yet nothing happens. Only the home page loads but the rest of the pages don't. Any ideas?

Comment: Those files will get regenerated. That is what I learned from those other reports. No sense in deleting them, you need to take your sites down.

Comment: It is a plugin that is generating these htaccess files. Downloading my site and debugging it using vsCode was the solution. Anyways, thank you all for your comments and support.

Comment: @ludwigsmith can you please tell us which plugin was causing this behaviour. I am having same problem and all Wordpress websites on my Hosting account are having same issue. I am struggling to find the cause.